# Is there a way to set the console height(in lines)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is it possible to set how many lines the console will print before it starts to erase the top ones? For example, is it possible to set it to 3 and only make the last 3 lines be visible? So:

```
std::cout<<"line 1!"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"line 2!"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"line 3!"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"line 4!"<<std::endl;
system("pause");
```

Would output:

```
line 3!
line 4!
Press any key to continue...
```

^without creating a scroll bar on the side.

I've been trying to use `Console::BufferHeight` but I can't seem to get it to work. This is the only thing I've been able to find that seems to be close to what I want to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.bufferheight.aspx But It just shows how to read it, not how to set the size. And for some reason typing just `std::cout<<System::Console::BufferHeight;` gives me scope errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ¤ `mode con lines=3`. for doing it programmatically, see the MSDN help about console functions. note: as I recall, last I checked they'd removed title "console functions" from the index, so perhaps you have to go at it a bit obliquely to find it. cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

- [SetConsoleWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Example,

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
SMALL_RECT rect = {0,0, 100, 100};
SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &rect)
```

---

Have a look at these as well (experiment with them):

- [SetConsoleScreenBufferSize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There is an example on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685113%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but could you please add an example of the code being used? I'm still new to programming, so the links doesn't really explain much to me. I tried: 

`HANDLE hConsole;
hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD bufferSize = {72, 72};
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hConsole, bufferSize);`

I got no errors, but that seems to have done nothing at all.

Comment: @Natriacid: Done. Use `SetConsoleWindowInfo` to set the dimension of console window.

Comment: After messing around with `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hConsole, bufferSize);` for a while I realized that it does work, but only to increase the size of the rows/columns. Trying to use it to remove the max rows/columns does nothing. Is there no way to remove them? Or am I just that bad with code? `SetConsoleWindowInfo` also seems to just move the window around and re-size it, unless I'm using it wrong.

Comment: @Natriacid: Did you see my code which uses `SetConsoleWindowInfo`? Did you try it in your code? I don't exactly know what you're taking about. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Im new to programming also, but I tried:

```
while(!cin.get())
{
}
```

and it worked,try to place it in the bottom of the code. It will work wonders on your console!

Try changing its position (put it in the middle of the code)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest keeping the lines yourself, in a quick class, say that cycles where to put the next line by using an iterator that is always set to point at the next line to be input into.
Next, use `FillConsoleOutputCharacter()` to print blanks over the lines you previously had printed there.
Then, use `SetConsoleCursorPosition()` to four(or however many lines you wanted) lines above where you want your input to start, and output each line in you cycle, starting at the one *after* your iterator. This prints all the lines in order from eldest to youngest.
It's been a while, so my knowledge of C++ is kinda hazy, but this should be pretty simple with the standard library and win32 library.